# Change SiteLogo via csom in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, site-logo

Regarding to this Question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313303/where-is-a-sitelogourl-in-csom).

How can i change the siteLogo to a new one?

Is it even possible to do it from a ConsoleApplication via CSOM?

Comment: I don't think this is possible by CSOM

Comment: yes you can change the site logo by updating the master page and deploying it using CSOM

Answer (score 1):

This can now be achieved through updates to the CSOM.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.sitelogourl(v=office.15).aspx

This was made available due to requests on UserVoice:
http://blogs.office.com/2014/08/13/uservoice-driving-improvements-sharepoint-api/